# C++ Operator Overload >>

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I hadn't found answer even if exist anywhere.
I have class and I want overload >> operator

That code compile but it don't work how I want. 
I want put value in all cells inside array, but it only work for 1st cell. Looks like my loop don't work.

Edited: 
Full code below. Btw sorry for language but this is my homework and teacher want that names.

```
    #include <cstdlib>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include <cmath>

    template <class T>
    class Wielomian {
    private:
        int stopien;
        T *wspolczynniki;
    public:
        friend std::ostream & operator << (std::ostream &output, Wielomian &w)
        {
            output << "Wielomian: ";
            for (int i = w.stopien-1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                output << w.wspolczynniki[i] << "x^" << i << " ";
                if (i)
                    output << "+ ";
            }
            return output;
        }
        friend std::istream & operator >> (std::istream &input, Wielomian &w)
        {
            int i = 0;
            do {
                input >> w.wspolczynniki[i++];
            } while (w.stopien < i);
            return input;
        }
        T operator () (T x)
        {
            T wynik = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < this->stopien; i++)
            {
                wynik += this->wspolczynniki[i] * pow(x,i);
            }
            return wynik;
        }
        T& operator[](const int index)
        {
            return wspolczynniki[index];
        }
        Wielomian operator + (const Wielomian &w)
        {
            const Wielomian *wiekszy;
            const Wielomian *mniejszy;
            if (w.stopien > this->stopien)
            {
                wiekszy = &w;
                mniejszy = this;
            }
            else
            {
                wiekszy = this;
                mniejszy = &w;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < mniejszy->stopien; i++)
                wiekszy->wspolczynniki[i] += mniejszy->wspolczynniki[i];
            return *wiekszy;
        }
        Wielomian operator - (const Wielomian &w)
        {
            const Wielomian *wiekszy;
            const Wielomian *mniejszy;
            if (w.stopien > this->stopien)
            {
                wiekszy = &w;
                mniejszy = this;
            }
            else
            {
                wiekszy = this;
                mniejszy = &w;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < mniejszy->stopien; i++)
                wiekszy->wspolczynniki[i] -= mniejszy->wspolczynniki[i];
            return *wiekszy;
        }
        Wielomian operator = (const Wielomian &w)
        {
            this->stopien = w.stopien;
            this->wspolczynniki = new float[this->stopien];
            memcpy(this->wspolczynniki, w.wspolczynniki, w.stopien * sizeof(double));
        }
        Wielomian(const Wielomian &w)
        {
            this->stopien = w.stopien;
            this->wspolczynniki = new float[this->stopien];
            memcpy(this->wspolczynniki, w.wspolczynniki, w.stopien * sizeof(double));
        }
        Wielomian(int stopien = 0, T wspolczynik[] = { 3 })
        {
            this->stopien = stopien;
            wspolczynniki = new T[this->stopien];
            for (int i = 0; i < stopien; i++)
            {
                this->wspolczynniki[i] = wspolczynik[i];
            }
        }
        ~Wielomian()
        {
            free(this->wspolczynniki);
        }

    };



    int main()
    {
        double tab[4] = {3,4,5,6};
        Wielomian<double> w1(4,tab);

        std::cin >> w1;
        std::cout << w1;


        std::cin.get();
        std::cin.get();
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Please create a [mre]. We need to see the `Wielomian()` constructor and the `<<` operator.

Comment: In particular, we also need information on what `wspolczynniki` points at, and what value `stopien` holds.   Those need to be pretty well aligned in your code (since it appears `w.stopien` is being used as an upper limit for an array index, `i`) and getting that wrong will give undefined behaviour (running past the end of a dynamically allocated array, etc)

Comment: The `+` and  `-` operations normally do not modify any of their operands.

Comment: Don't use `free` with memory you got from `new []` – it has undefined behaviour. Use `delete []`.

Comment: And note that `Wielomian<int>(2)` will cause undefined behaviour.

Comment: In addition to the `free` and `new[]` information, I would suggest you using  `std::vectore<T> wspolczynniki` instead of `T *wspolczynniki`, that would simplify your code. (But as it is homework you might not have a choice)

Comment: Don't understand the problem, because your program is working fine as operators are executed properly.

Comment: t.niese yea I know but it is homework  
Mannoj I want use ">>" for all cells not only 1st. Now when I compile it my program only change value for cell "0"
molbdnilo ok, thanks I will check this.

Comment: @Peter "wieloman"-> "polynomial", "wspolczynniki" -> "coefficients", "stopien" -> "degree".

Comment: @Spencer - that's all well and good, but not what I was asking.  I asked for the OP to provide code showing how it establishes relationships between the variables.   The translations you give may reflect intent.  They may not reflect what the code actually does - and that is fairly likely, since the OP has indicated a function is not behaving as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `while` condition in `operator >>` is wrong. In your code you have:

```
int i = 0;
do {
  input >> w.wspolczynniki[i++];
} while (w.stopien < i);
```

`i` is `0` at the beginning, and then after `input >> w.wspolczynniki[i++]` it is `1`. The `while` condition is `(w.stopien < i)` so if `w.stopien` (which is `4` in your example)  is smaler then `i` which is `1` in the first iteration, you will continue the loop. But `4 < 1` is `false` you will always only read one value.

So get your `do-while` to work you would need to change it to `(w.stopien > i)`. But as you test if your index `i` is in the correct range you shouldn't use a `do-while` at all, but a `while` loop.

```
int i = 0;
while (i < w.stopien) {
  input >> w.wspolczynniki[i++];
}
```

Or even a `for` loop, which would make clearer what you are doing:

```
for(int i=0; i< w.stopien; i++) {
  input >> w.wspolczynniki[i];
}
```

In addition to that - and what is already mentioned in the comments - never combine the memory allocations and deallocation that don't belong together. If you use `new[]` then you have to use `delete[]` to free the memory and not `free`.

And don't use signed numbers (`int`) for indices, so `stopien` and `i` should be unsigned (e.g. `size_t`). And for `stopien` you should ensure on construction that it is `1` or larger.

And if you are allowed to you should switch form `T* wspolczynniki` to `std::vector<T> wspolczynniki` that would allow you to get rid of the copy constructor, the assignment operator, the destructor, you would not need int stopien`, and you could simplify other parts of the code using [algorithm](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm), or at least keep that you normally would use a`std::vector` (or other containers) then doing the allocation and the copying yourself.

Comment: @DonQnei Such problems can be easily spotted if you step line by line through that part of your code using a debugger. That will save you time looking for the error your self, or waiting for an answer.

Comment: Or he could check `stopien==0` in the constructor then use `do..while` in the more frequently used members to avoid that extra check.

Comment: @Spencer Using a `while` or a `for` is in this case better than a `do..while`. If you see that `do..while` in a code review you would need the check the whole code if nothing in the code would change `stopien` to `0` and that's bad. Using the loops correctly will prevent you from such bugs right at the place where you use the code, making the code safer and more maintainable.

Comment: @t.neise You'd only do it if (1) it was a real requirement that the value never be 0 and (2) you really, really needed the extra cycles (which is unlikely). With (1) you need to check the whole code anyway. You'd put an assert in the source code so that a debug build would make the extra check but the release build wouldn't. Never assume the most naive case.

Comment: @Spencer it is not about if it is a requirement that you want to support `0` as value, but about preventing bugs. Out of bounds array access are one of the most reason for undefined behavior and not predictable crashes or potential security problems caused by them. And using the correct loop is the easiest way to minimize such problems. Especially if the code base gets larger those relations are hard to keep track of, so you want to ensure the correctness a the place where you use it. And about the saving of one comparison here, you have IO in the loop so this really does not matter.

Comment: @t.neise If you really need a bounds check, it should be done explicitly, not buried in the loop condition. And now I suspect wer're going to be bumped to chat.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204841/discussion-between-spencer-and-t-niese).